# I have a dataframe whose length does not correspond

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataframe but in the output the number of rows does not correspond to the length i am so confused

```
df['clean']

113        apc started it so lets finish what they started 
235        upon all these votes from katsina apc governm...
1796       when two or more people are contesting for an...
1798        deji said peter obi is jumping from church t...
1850      before amnesia set in this was you and lemme s...
                                ...                        
378726                                                  nan
378727                                                  nan
378728                                                  nan
378729                                                  nan
378730                                                  nan
Name: clean, Length: 63664, dtype: object
```

Comment: This qustion is not clear, Please provide exactly what is required ?, and sample output

Comment: This could be due to various reasons such as merge, setting values etc., without the proper explanation this is tedious to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your left column is the index column. It doesn't have to count your rows, and it can be basically anything, even a [`DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html). If you want the index to count the rows, you can use [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) or provide your code from the declaration of `df` to this point.

With a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), someone could tell you where you changed the index, unless you imported `df` that way.